# Optimise AJAX - Laravel function

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm struggling a bit with some formulas, the idea is to have just one formula/function for everything, so it'll be easy to maintain and will be robust.

The problem is trying to combine AJAX calls and laravel functions.

From one side I have a AJAX Datatables controller (the calls need to be in this format):

```
public function userData(Request $request)
    {
        $event = User::select(
            'users.*',
            DB::raw('IFNULL(b.balance,0) as balance'),
        )
        ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT seller_id, SUM(total) as balance FROM transactions WHERE concept IN ("TPV") AND status = "ok" GROUP by buyer_id)as b'), 'b.seller_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->get();
        return $this->formatView($request, $event, 'user'); 
    }
```

Then, the formula I use for the rest of the web is in a Function inside a Model:

```
public function Balance($seller_id = false){
        return Transaction::emitted()
            ->where('event_id', $this->id)
            ->where('seller_id', $this->seller_id)
            ->whereIn('concept', ['TPV'])
            ->where('status', 'ok')
            ->sum('total'); 
    }
```

The question is: Do you have an idea of how to use just one formula/function for everything?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in your controller method**

Do common calculations in separate method and call it here. Then change format of response in below sections

```
if ($request->expectsJson()){
   //send response to ajax here in json format. note that you should set ajax dataType:'json'
}
//send response for web here.
```